# Accessing the elements of a list - python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list with the following structure and I would like to have the information for each element separately, for example the positions.

```
joint_trajectory: 
  header: 
    seq: 0
    stamp: 
      secs: 0
      nsecs:         0
    frame_id: "world"
  joint_names: 
    - shoulder_pan_joint
    - shoulder_lift_joint
    - elbow_joint
    - wrist_1_joint
    - wrist_2_joint
    - wrist_3_joint
  points: 
    - 
      positions: [-0.00025209861478181494, 0.004307795221944133, 0.0006349868678086068, 0.0010435817857663565, -4.234193532681729e-05, 3.768785300195532e-05]
      velocities: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
      accelerations: [-0.6884183719945808, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
      effort: []
      time_from_start: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs:         0
    - 
      positions: [-0.04992968849098622, -0.08433208536812643, -0.13655855187577923, 0.22660211433504318, 0.028808576199230457, 0.15709421547345312]
      velocities: [-0.2239121377558192, -0.39952713492749836, -0.6183733676072944, 1.0166615034673043, 0.1300399389709771, 0.7079019520801277]
      accelerations: [-0.6943738586354055, -1.2389734700835597, -1.9176374521112265, 3.1527686625836706, 0.40326681306781165, 2.1952745167278875]
      effort: []
      time_from_start: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs: 379899770
    - 
      positions: [-0.09960727836719062, -0.172971965958197, -0.27375209061936706, 0.45216064688432, 0.05765949433378773, 0.3141507430939043]
      velocities: [-0.36247695177120814, -0.6467687704198166, -1.0010448544385069, 1.6458078889936585, 0.21051328953911835, 1.1459769189588018]
      accelerations: [-0.652382575660194, -1.1640482911845413, -1.8016710229404767, 2.9621094097625744, 0.37887981944549876, 2.0625183763666244]
      effort: []
      time_from_start: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs: 536582108
    - 
      positions: [-0.149284868243395, -0.2616118465482675, -0.4109456293629549, 0.6777191794335968, 0.086510412468345, 0.47120727071435536]
      velocities: [-0.44476904942193296, -0.7936028202890654, -1.2283091825886876, 2.019450910580548, 0.2583055149340806, 1.4061447560022973]
      accelerations: [-0.6557433669411694, -1.170044961686803, -1.8109524484275814, 2.977368909094765, 0.38083164348439513, 2.0731435739650403]
      effort: []
      time_from_start: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs: 658372363
    - 
      positions: [-0.19896245811959942, -0.35025172713833813, -0.5481391681065427, 0.9032777119828737, 0.11536133060290228, 0.6282637983348066]
      velocities: [-0.515602863886791, -0.9199918192632637, -1.4239294148374249, 2.3410681888216205, 0.2994431906421152, 1.630087039951357]
      accelerations: [-0.7018697640759863, -1.2523484378471594, -1.9383387340382296, 3.1868034343091045, 0.40762015941069035, 2.2189729465994303]
      effort: []
      time_from_start: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs: 761514193
    - 
      positions: [-0.2486400479958038, -0.4388916077284087, -0.6853327068501306, 1.1288362445321505, 0.14421224873745955, 0.7853203259552577]
      velocities: [-0.5753051920982908, -1.0265188721417164, -1.5888080592921592, 2.612143528320158, 0.33411610830911154, 1.8188369447498993]
      accelerations: [-0.5950528657343278, -1.0617547086102592, -1.6433447877210596, 2.701806821118893, 0.34558483126529427, 1.8812695437867313]
      effort: []
      time_from_start: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs: 851909030
```

I print the list but when I try to access each element the error is that the element is not defined
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'joint_names'

This is the code:

```
pred_plans = []
    pred_plans.append(copy.copy(plan1))
    print(type(pred_plans))        

    for p in pred_plans.joint_names: print p
```

Answer (score 0):

This could have been a comment but my reputation!

Lists in python are accessed using indices, you may try pred_plans[i], where limit on i can be given by len(pred_plans).
This may be helpful:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/

Dictionaries in python are accessed using keys.

Comment: Yes it's true. But in this case everything is in index 0 (ex: print pred_plans [0]), print the entire list, how can I access the other parts later? When printing like this the whole structure appears, hence my question

Comment: You need to use nested for loops for nested lists. If don't want to iterate through the whole list you can use 'break' statements too. 
Dictionary looks better suited for your case.